# How is allocation/deallocation of objects in standard template library done

Tags: c++, stl

Most of the time I am confused about how allocation/deallocation of stl objects is done. For example: take this loop.

```
vector<vector<int>> example;
for(//some conditions) {
    vector<int>row;
    for(//some conditions) {
        row.push_back(k);  //k is some int.
    }
    example.push_back(row);
}
```

In this case what is happening with the object row. I can still see values if I access via example, which means that when I do `example.push_back(row)` a new copy is created. Am I correct. Is there a good way to prevent the same(if I am correct).

Also can anyone give references where I can read up how is allocation/deallocation handled in `stl` or what are best practices to avoid such memory copying issue(in case of large applications).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It isn't a must that every `push_back` will lead to new memory allocation; if the container already has memory, it'll use it to construct a new object. Look up `std::vector::reserve`.

Comment: In this example, you could do `example.push_back(std::move(row));`, since nothing uses `row` after that.

Comment: The fact is that `std::vector` copies data internally (and sometimes it has to allocate more memory to handle the increasing number of elements). You can always use pointers to mitigate object copy overhead but remember to delete them afterwards (or otherwise use smart pointers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I do example.push_back(row) a new copy is created. Am I correct.

Yes.

> Is there a good way to prevent the same

Why would you want to prevent it?  That behaviour is what makes `vector` simple and safe to use.

The standard library containers have value semantics, so they take a copy of the values you add to them and they manage the lifetime of those values, so you don't need to worry about it.

> Also can anyone give references where I can read up how is allocation/deallocation handled in stl

Have you never heard of a search engine?  Try http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Allocators.html for starters.

> or what are best practices to avoid such memory copying issue(in case of large applications).

In general: forget about it.  You usually don't need to worry about it, unless profiling has shown there's a performance problem.

`std::vector` does allow more fine-grained control over its memory usage, see the **New members** section and footnotes at http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html for more information.

For your example, you could add a new row to the `example` container then add the `int` values directly to it:

```
vector<vector<int>> example;
for(/*some conditions*/) {
    example.resize(example.size()+1);
    vector<int>& row = example.back();
    for(/*some conditions*/) {
        row.push_back(k);  //k is some int.
    }
}
```

Even better would be to reserve enough capacity in the vector in advance:

```
vector<vector<int>> example;
example.reserve( /* maximum expected size of vector */ );
for(/*some conditions*/) {
    example.resize(example.size()+1);
    vector<int>& row = example.back();
    for(/*some conditions*/) {
        row.push_back(k);  //k is some int.
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to prevent it as it is more efficient. I do not know a way, I asked it so as to be sure. Heard of a search engine and used it too, but I asked to give you resources to read in case there is a way to avoid it. I guess as your answer suggest there are no resources on that topic as it is not of that importance("forget about it part"). And as for the using `reserve()`. It is a very naive heuristic and if I know the size before than I would go with allocating memory with new rather than using stl(exception etc. can be handled). Anyways thanks for the answer, it was partially helpful.:)

Comment: I gave you resources to read on that topic, read the answer more carefully. You'd be best off reading a good book like Josuttis, since it's a broad topic that requires a good author to explain it fully

Comment: Also my answer showed _exactly_ how to avoid `example.push_back(row)` creating a new copy, which was what you asked for. Maybe you need to read the code more carefully too.

Answer (score 0):

All an stl implementation has to do is obey the standard.

But `std::swap` is often used to switch the contents of a vector with another. This can be used to prevent value copies from being taken and is a good way of achieving efficiency, at least in the pre C++11 world. (In your case, push back an empty vector and swap it with the one you've created).

Comment: Or push an empty vector and add the `int`s directly to it

Comment: @Jonathan Wakely; yes in this cast given it's a vector of ints, that's very good advice; +1 helpful. My answer is to be read in a more general context for larger data types.